# Safari form POST disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari

We're having the same HTML and PHP for months. All of a sudden, seems like Safari changed the way it submits Radio-Buttons. On-Submit we're running a JS-function to validate all Inputs.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.querySelectorAll('input.ignore[type="radio"]').forEach( /** @param {HTMLInputElement} radio */ function(radio) {
        console.log(radio.disabled); // OUTPUT: false
        radio.disabled = true;
        console.log(radio.disabled); // OUTPUT: true
        _func_setHiddenFIeld();      // we set the value of the checked Radio button as value of the hidden input
    });

    // now post
    this.submit();

    // reactivate radios
   form.querySelectorAll('input.ignore[type="radio"]').forEach( /** @param {HTMLInputElement} radio */ function(radio) {
        console.log(radio.disabled); // OUTPUT: true
        radio.disabled = false;
        console.log(radio.disabled); // OUTPUT: false
        _func_setHiddenFIeld();      // we set the value of the checked Radio button as value of the hidden input
    });
});

<form action="/form/debug.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" class="" name="TEST1" value="">
    <label for="ID1">
        <input class="form-radio ignore" required="required" data-field="TEST1" type="radio" id="ID1" name="ignore_TEST1" value="one">
        one
    </label>
    <label for="ID2">
        <input class="form-radio ignore" required="required" data-field="TEST1" type="radio" id="ID2" name="ignore_TEST1" value="two">
        two
    </label>
</form>
```

All Browsers (Edge/Firefox/Chrome/Opera) do POST `name="TEST1"` this field only. Except Safari, Safari Posts two Fields
`name="TEST1"` plus the checked radio button `name="ignore_TEST1"` or `name="ignore_TEST2"`.

Did anything changed?

**Update #1:** I added more JS I found. We reactivate the radios as soon as the form is submit. When I remove the "//reactivate radios" part it works. So there is anything different now with using `this.submit()`.